# How to get textarea values as a separate variables?

Tags: php, variables, textarea, display

My Html code is

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name='test'></textarea>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My input in textarea  as

```
Hi
How
are
you
```

by pressing enter key am giving input in next lines in textarea.

Now while displaying

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
echo $array = $_POST['test'];
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Its giving result as

```
Hi
How
are
you
```

Result will be stored under same variable. Is it possible to get each line values in separate variables?

Comment: Explode by newline? `explode("\n", $_POST['test']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer;

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
print_r(explode("\n", $_POST['test']));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: `'\n'` should be `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

try this. Hope it helps.

```
$var = $_POST['test'];

$array = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $var)));

$variables = [];
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $row){

    $variables["variable_$i"] = $row;
$i++;
}

$var1 = $variables["variable_1"];
$var2 = $variables["variable_2"];
$var3 = $variables["variable_3"];

echo "1st variable ".$var1." 2nd variable ".$var2."3th variable ".$var3;
```